# Can a MasterAir Cooler 8 fit in a Cooler Master Elite 110?

Tags: motherboard, cooling, computer-building, case, dimensions

I'm currently building a PC and about to finalize my purchase--components all listed below. As far as I know, all of the components are compatible with each other. I've already got a standard 3.5" WD Red HDD and 2.5" Kingston SSD, so those components are not included below.

My Concerns:

- Will the `MasterAir Maker 8` fit on the `Gigabyte LG 1151 Micro ATX Motherboard` inside of the `Cooler Master Elite 110 Micro ATX Case` alongside the `ASUS GTX 970 Graphic Card`?
- If not, what alternative case or CPU cooling fan could I get as an alternative that fits either the case or fan within similar price ranges as the aforementioned items?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the MasterAir Maker 8 fit on the Gigabyte LG 1151 Micro ATX
>   Motherboard inside of the Cooler Master Elite 110 Micro ATX Case
>   alongside the ASUS GTX 970 Graphic Card?

[Here](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/masterair-maker-8/) are the `MasterAir Maker 8` specifications:

[image]

[Here](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/TURBOGTX970OC4GD5/specifications/) are the ASUS TURBO-GTX970-OC-4GD5 specifications:

[image]

[Here](http://www.coolermaster.com/case/mini-itx-elite-series/elite110/) are the `Cooler Master Elite 110 Micro ATX Case specifications:

[image]

[Here](http://www.sentey.com/en/xpp-725-watts-xpp725-hs) are the specifications for the Sentry XPP725-HS PSU:

[image]

The graphic card you have selected is too large for the case. The heat sink is also is too large for the case.  The PSU you have selected is also too large for the case.

Comment: Could you recommend a case that would fit all of the desired components? Possibly within a similar price range.

Comment: @FatalSleep - If I did that your question and my answer would be deleted for not being helpful to the community.  Hardware recommendations are specifically not on topic.  If I provided a hardware recommendation I would have to vote, to delete my own answer, so I won't be supply specific hardware recommendations.  *You are more then capable of looking the dimensions of products to determine if something will fit.*  I know you can make that determination because you have the mental capacity to even ask this question.

Comment: Oh, correct, that's in the off-topic section. I'll scour around for one.